# Verifying that $\Gamma$ is a homomorphism and $\Gamma(G)\cong G/Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group. Then the set of automorphisms of $G$, denoted by $\operatorname{Aut} G$, is a group under composition. Also, for $g\in G$, the map $\gamma_{g}\colon G\to G$ defined by $x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $G$. Define $\Gamma\colon G\to \operatorname{Aut} G$ by $\Gamma(g)=\gamma_g$.

> Verify that $\Gamma$ is a homomorphism, and then let $Z=Z(G)$, the center of $G$, and show that $\Gamma(G)\cong G/Z$ (rememberthat $Z\lhd G$).

---

For the first part, this is what I tried: Let $a,b\in G$, where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary. Then $\Gamma(ab)=\gamma_{ab}$; thus, we have the following:
$$
x\mapsto (ab)x(ab)^{-1}=abxb^{-1}a^{-1}=a(bxb^{-1})a^{-1}=\gamma_{a}\circ\gamma_{b}=\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b).
$$
Hence, we have that $\Gamma$ is a homomorphism, as desired. Does this look right?

---

This part I found to be trickier. To show $\Gamma(G)\cong G/Z$, we consider the mapping $\theta\colon\Gamma(G)\to G/Z$ where $\theta(x)=\gamma_g\mapsto f$ such that $f(\gamma_g)=e=\operatorname{id}_{\operatorname{Aut} G}$ is one-to-one, onto, and $\theta(a+b)=\theta(\Gamma(a))+\theta(\Gamma(b))$. Consider $$\theta(\Gamma(a))+\theta(\Gamma(b))=\theta(axa^{-1})+\theta(bxb^{-1})=h(axa^{-1})+g(bxb^{-1})=exe^{-1}+exe^{-1}=exe^{-1}=f(ab)x(ab)^{-1}=\theta(\Gamma(ab)).$$
Thus the homomorphism property holds. To show that $\theta$ is onto, pick an arbitrary element $f$ of $G/Z$. Then there exists $a\in\Gamma(G)$ such that $f(axa^{-1})=e$. Then $\theta(\Gamma(a))\to f$, so $\theta$ is onto. To show $\theta$ is one-to-one, consider $\theta(\Gamma(a))=\theta(\Gamma(b))$. Then $f(axa^{-1})=f(bxb^{-1})$. It follows that $a=b$. Thus, $\theta$ is one-to-one, concluding the proof.

---

Does this all look right or is there a more elegant way of going about it, particularly the second part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is fine.

For the second part, what makes more sense is to consider the homomorphism 
$$\Gamma : G \to \Gamma(G)
$$
which is obviously surjective. Hence all you have to show is that the kernel of $\Gamma$ is equal to $Z$. In other words what remains is to show that the automorphism $\gamma_g(x) = g x g^{-1}$ is the identity if and only if $g$ commutes with every $x$ ...

Comment: Is there an easy way to show that the automorphism $\gamma_g(x)=gxg^{-1}$ is the identity iff $g$ commutes with ever $x$? Or is this long and drawn out?

Comment: @riddler: Contrary to being long and drawn out, it is an immediate consequence of the definitions.

Comment: If $g$ is in the kernel, then $\gamma_g$ is the identity map. That is, $gxg^{-1}=x$ for all $x\in G$. So $gx=xg$ for all $x\in G$. Thus, $g\in Z(G)$. Hence, $\Gamma(G)\cong G/Z$. Right?

Comment: That's about right.

Comment: Is there something missing?

Comment: Maybe just observing that the converse is also true: if $\gamma_g$ is the identity map then $g$ is in the kernel.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks!